# How to explain "compactification of a dimension"

Tags: topology, yang-mills, compactification, kaluza-klein

The first paragraph of the wikipedia entry on "[compactification (physics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_(physics))" explains that it
"means changing a theory with respect to one of its space-time dimensions. Instead of having a theory with this dimension being infinite, one changes the theory so that this dimension has a finite length".

To someone mathematically inclined this sounds very confusing. It seems that "theory" is used where "model" is meant, and "dimension" where "coordinate" is meant.
In any case, what is the truth about compactification, as the word is actually used in physics?

The wikipedia entry says that the range of the new coordinate must be of finite size. It does not say that it must be compact. The open interval (0,1) has finite length and is not compact, would it be a candidate for the range of a coordinate that is "compactified"?

Conversely, compactification in mathematics does not involve size. To compactify the real line R, the default is to add one or two new elements "at infinity", which appears to make the range larger instead of smaller.

Comment: What definitions of "theory", "model", "dimension", and "coordinate" are you using in this question?

Comment: Indeed, when we talk about compactifying a dimension, we just mean giving it a finite length, as measured by the metric.

Comment: I quoted wikipedia verbatim, and there is no explanation of "dimension" or "theory" given. I take "coordinate" to be a better term then "dimension" in the context, since the wikipedia entry for "dimension" strongly suggests that it means the number of coordinates needed to represent a point. And "model" to be a better notion in the context, since we are not supposed to apply a different theory to the new object, so far as I can see.

Comment: I suspect that we not just mean giving it finite length. After all the word "compactification" suggests that we might want to make it compact as well. In Kaluza-Klein and Yang-Mills theories this seems required. But I cannot tell whether there are exceptions.